# SeD vs Postfix logs

Tags: regex, sed, postfix-mta

I am writing a script to extract the message id from postfix logs but the logs can contain different date stamps so the number of fields can differ, therefore awk '{ print $6 }' which is the message ID field does not work all the time and I heard with SED it's faster too.

So the only data I need from each line of the log is and ID:

7B01038BFDB

```
cat mail.log | grep 'postfix' | grep -i email@address.com | sed -n 's/.*[0-9A-Z]{11}:*/\1/p'
```

But this regexp does not work.

Comment: you should post the fragment of your log file

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your `sed` pattern to

```
sed  's/.*\([0-9A-Z]\{11\}\):.*/\1/'
          ^^        ^^  ^^^^ ^^
```

To use a backreference, you need to define a capturing group with `\(...\)` and the range quantifier also must be escaped in BRE POSIX. Besides, the pattern should end with `.*` to match the rest of the line.

Comment: Hello, Although it works it will just print out junk lines where there the id is not present eg: `echo "aaaaaaaa" | sed  's/.*\([0-9A-Z]\{11\}\):.*/\1/' will result -> aaaaaaaa.` If the ID is not present I don't want any results.

Comment: @munin24 Then `grep` the lines that contain the pattern, say, with `grep '[0-9A-Z]\{11\}:'`.